# When I place two pie charts inside a panelGrid they disappear

Tags: layout, primefaces, charts, pie-chart, panelgrid

I want to place **2 primefaces pie charts side by side horizontally**. I've put them into a **panelGrid** like that:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
<p:pieChart title="chart1" value="#{chartController.modelChart1}" legendPosition="w" showDataLabels="true" id="chartOne" />

<p:pieChart title="chart2" value="#{chartController.modelChart2}" legendPosition="w" showDataLabels="true" id="ChartTwo" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

But they simply **disappeared** when I added the panelGrid.

What's the problem or is there another way to place the 2 charts side by side (on the same line) without using the panelGrid??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:panel style="width:100px;">
       <p:pieChart title="chart1" value="#{chartController.modelChart1}" legendPosition="w" showDataLabels="true" id="chartOne" />
    </p:panel>

    <p:panel style="width:100px;">
       <p:pieChart title="chart2" value="#{chartController.modelChart2}" legendPosition="w" showDataLabels="true" id="ChartTwo" />
    </p:panel>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Great it works (but with a width of 400px for example) :))) thx a lot :)